# Error while installing Crypt::SSLeay on linux

Tags: linux, perl, ssl, openssl

So i'm trying to install Apache with SSL ergo Apache Openssl and SSLeay. I'm done with Apache2 and Openssl know i'm having difficulties getting SSLeay installed. I get as far as `perl Makefile.PL` after that all commands fail.

```
perl Makefile.PL    
Found multiple possibilities for OpenSSL
      /opt/ssl (OpenSSL 0.9.8r)
      /usr (OpenSSL 0.9.8p)
    Which SSL install path do you want to use? [/opt/ssl]

build information

================================================

ssl library: OpenSSL 0.9.8r in /opt/ssl
ssl header:  openssl/ssl.h
libraries:   -L/opt/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lgcc
include dir: -I/opt/ssl/include

================================================

Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lgcc
Writing Makefile for Crypt::SSLeay
The test suite can attempt to connect to public servers
to ensure that the code is working properly. If you are
behind a strict firewall or have no network connectivity,
these tests may fail (through no fault of the code).
Do you want to run the live tests (y/N)? [N]
```

I choose the /usr installation because that is the one that I have openssl-devel installed on, since i looked at [this question, that is simmilar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238738/unable-to-install-the-crypt-ssleay-module) and found out that openssl-devel is needed. So I installed openssl-devel

```
rpm -qi openssl
Name        : openssl                      Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 0.9.8a                            Vendor: SUSE LINUX Products GmbH, Nuernberg, Germany
Release     : 18.36                         Build Date: Mon 27 Jul 2009 03:55:03 PM CEST
Install Date: Mon 18 Jan 2010 10:42:42 AM CET      Build Host: deacon.suse.de
Group       : Productivity/Networking/Security   Source RPM: openssl-0.9.8a-18.36.src.rpm
Size        : 2998754                          License: BSD 3-Clause
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Mon 27 Jul 2009 03:57:14 PM CEST, Key ID a84edae89c800aca
Packager    : http://bugs.opensuse.org
URL         : http://www.openssl.org/
Summary     : Secure Sockets and Transport Layer Security


rpm -qi openssl-devel
Name        : openssl-devel                Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 0.9.8p                            Vendor: PLD
Release     : 1                             Build Date: Fri 19 Nov 2010 12:24:41 PM CET

Install Date: Wed 05 Oct 2011 03:47:56 PM CEST      Build Host: x86-64.titanium.pld-linux.org
Group       : Development/Libraries         Source RPM: openssl-0.9.8p-1.src.rpm
Size        : 2003899                          License: Apache-like
Signature   : (none)
Packager    : PLD
URL         : http://www.openssl.org/
Summary     : Development part of OpenSSL Toolkit libraries
Description :<br/>
Development part of OpenSSL library.
Distribution: PLD Titanium
```

But know i still get the following error when i run `make`

```
make
cc -c  -I/opt/ssl/include -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DTHREADS_HAVE_PIDS -DDEBUGGING -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -Wdeclaration-after-statement -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -fmessage-length=0 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -Wall -pipe   -DVERSION=\"0.58\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.58\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   SSLeay.c
SSLeay.c: In function âXS_Crypt__SSLeay__CTX_newâ:
SSLeay.c:118: warning: unused variable âpacknameâ
SSLeay.c: In function âXS_Crypt__SSLeay__Conn_newâ:
SSLeay.c:395: warning: unused variable âpacknameâ
SSLeay.c: In function âXS_Crypt__SSLeay__CTX_use_pkcs12_fileâ:
SSLeay.c:287: warning: âRETVALâ may be used uninitialized in this function
Running Mkbootstrap for Crypt::SSLeay ()
chmod 644 SSLeay.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so
cc  -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 SSLeay.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so       \
   -L/opt/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto        

/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.1.2/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /opt/ssl/lib/libssl.a(s2_clnt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/opt/ssl/lib/libssl.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.so] Error 1
```

I would think that the reason is that perl does not find the openssl-devel library, if so how do i link it so it can be found.

Thanks in advance Almightybob

Comment: There are a whole lot of things I have to fix with `Crypt::SSLeay`. A redone `Makefile.PL` is one of them. One of these days, I am going to get around to it. In the mean time, please use a prepackaged version if your distribution provides one.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the version that has been pre-build for your distribution?

```
$ sudo yum install perl-Crypt-SSLeay
```

(Or some close equivalent)

Comment: is that possible with 'yast' as well, i don't want to take the time to install yum

Answer (score 0):

If it can't find the library you usually get an `undefined symbol` error. This lookes more like it found the library but didn't like it. Is it possible you're trying to use a 32bit openssl with 64bit perl or vise versa?

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about the pieces of software.

On openSUSE and related distros, simply `sudo zypper install apache2`. The Apache httpd v2 already includes a binding to OpenSSL named mod_ssl; this command will automatically install all necessary dependencies to **serve** content over SSL, including the OpenSSL library. It is not needed to compile anything.

SSLeay is part of the Perl HTTP **client** stack. It is good for accessing someone else's content on a remote server over SSL. This is the opposite of what you want, but if you desire it anyway, first [add the repository](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aAdd_package_repositories) [`devel:language:perl`](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/perl/), then install the package `perl-LWP-Protocol-https`. Again, this will automatically pull in the required dependencies, including `perl-Net-SSLeay`.

To add Perl stuff which is commonly used in conjunction with your Apache web server, add the repository [`Apache:Modules`](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Apache:/Modules/), then also install the packages `apache2-mod_apreq2`, `apache2-mod_perl`, `libapreq2`, `perl-Apache2-Request`.